# Deleting duplicate points by attribute in shapefile using QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, point, extract, z-value

I've got a point shapefile which has a single attribute (elevation Z) and there are a lot of duplicate points (several points in the same location but each one has a different Z value). I would like to generate two shapefiles:

- One in which I get rid of all the duplicates and keep only the point with the highest Z value at each location
- One in which I get rid of all the duplicates and keep only the point with the lowest Z value at each location

Would there be a way to do this using the `"Select by Expression"` tool for instance?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using the `minimum()` and `maximum()` expressions with `$geometry` as a filter?

Comment: So in the minimum() or maximum() functions, if I use the $geometry as a filter, what should I use as a group_by value? I've added an ID column which has a single ID (integer increasing with an increment of 1) so I've got ID and Z as attributes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Select by expression with the following expression, then use [`Extract Selected Features`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#qgissaveselectedfeatures).

Explanation: The expression uses `overlay_nearest()` with a very small distance (tolerance value) to get an array of the z values of all points clustered together, then gets the maximum value using `array_max()`. Check if the current point's z value equals this maximum.

*Be aware: it seems you don't have an [actual z-value](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html?highlight=overlay_nearest#z), but an attribute named `z`. In this case, in the expression replace `z($geometry)` with `"z"` (3 times).*

```
z($geometry)=  
array_max(   -- maximum z value (for minimum: replace with array_min)
    array_prepend( 
        overlay_nearest(  -- find all nearby points... 
            @layer,  -- ... from the same layer...
            z($geometry), -- ... get their z values...
            max_distance:=0.01,  -- ... not further distance from current point than this distance
            limit:=-1  -- ...get all points
        ), 
        z($geometry)  -- add current point to array
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I tried this expression but it doesn't select any of the points and tells me "no matching feature(s) found" although I have a lot of overlaying points (duplicates). I also tried reducing or increasing the max_distance in you expression but it's still the same result so no features selected.

Comment: Can you provide sample data?

Comment: I've just added an image to my original post which shows typically how my data looks like.

Comment: Your image shows an attribute table with a field named `z`. But an attribute is not the same as an actual z-value. That might be the problem. Replace `z($geometry)` in the expression with `z` three times. Then it should work.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue, I replaced it by a Z and that now works fine. Thank you!